# Tire - find record containing all words

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tire

I have a problem concerning rails tire gem and its search.
Let's say I have a search query `'alpha street smith'` and only one record in ES containing these three words but in different columns. So for example company_name is `'alpha'`, company_address is `'street'` and company_director_name is `'smith'`.
Tire finds this record, but it also returns records which contain either one words from the query. For example if company_name is `'alpha'` but no other terms match, it still gets returned. 
So how can I achieve that only records that contain all searched terms get returned?